# Java JMS Messaging

Tags: java, spring, jboss, messaging, amqp

I have a working example of sending message to server and server receiving it via qpid messaging. Here is simple hello world to send to server :

http://pastebin.com/M7mSECJn

And here is server which receives requests and sends response(the current client doesn't receive response) :

http://pastebin.com/2mEeuzrV

Here is my property file :

http://pastebin.com/TLEFdpXG

They all work perfectly, I can see the messages in the qpid queue via Qpid JMX management console. These examples are downloaded from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/qpid/trunk/qpid/java/client/example (someone may need it also).

I've done Jboss messaging using spring before, but I can't manage to do the same with qpid. With jboss inside applicationsContext I had beans jndiTemplate, conectionFactory, destinationQueue, and jmscontainer like this :

```
<!-- Queue configuration -->
 <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
  <property name="environment">
   <props>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:1099</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">admin</prop>
    <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">admin</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
  <property name="jndiName" value="ConnectionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="queueDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
  <property name="jndiName">
   <value>queue/testQueue</value>
  </property>
 </bean>

  <bean id="jmsContainer"
  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
  <property name="destination" ref="queueDestination" />
  <property name="messageListener" ref="listener" />
 </bean>
```

and of course sender and listener :

```
 <bean id="sender" class="com.practice.Sender">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
  <property name="queueDestination" ref="queueDestination" />
 </bean>


 <bean id="listener" class="com.practice.MsgListener" />
```

Now I'd like to rewrite this qpid example using spring context logic. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Spring offers the JmsTemplate class. Check [this](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-jms.html) website out that has an example of how to setup the template (with activemq)

For your specific example try replacing the `jmsContainer` this:

```
<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
</bean>
```

You'll also have to change your code to use the spring JmsTemplate:

```
public class MessageSender  {

    private Destination destination;
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate)  {
        this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
    }

    public void setDestination(Destination destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void sendMessage() { 
        MessageCreator creator = new MessageCreator() {
            public Message createMessage(Session session) {
                TextMessage message = null;
                try  {
                    message = session.createTextMessage();
                    message.setStringProperty("text", "Hello, World!");
                }
                catch (JMSException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return message;
            }
        };  
    jmsTemplate.send(destination, creator);
    }
}
```

There's also good documentation on the springsource site for [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html)

Comment: Sorry I couldn't configure the spring appcontext properly can you please post other configurations bean for your example it doesn't have to be for mine so I can just see sample then implement in mine